# Unable to fetch application channel config after updating consenter certificates incorrectly

Tags: certificate, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

As part of the certificate renewal procedure, I simultaneously updated the system channel consenter certificates (tls certs) in channel configuration for all three orderers. I understand that the correct procedure is to update consenter certificate sequentially across all channels, resume the orderer with the most recent certificate, and then update the next consenter certificate. Unfortunately, after I incorrectly updated channel config, I am unable to access application channel config (was receiving "SERVICE UNAVAILABLE" error) and now my certificates are also expired. Is there a way to revert the consenter certificates in the system channel so that I can update the certificates using the proper procedure?
We have 3 orderers following RAFT protocol, 4 peers and 2 application channels.